# Decomposition of a cycle as a product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Can someone please explain the rules pertaining to different ways to write a cycle decomposition as products of 2-cycles, an example from textbook:
I understand this  $$ (12345) = (54)(53)(52)(51)  ,$$ but it also can be written 
$$ (12345) = (54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)   $$ which I don't understand how it can be.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the right hand sides and multiplying them?

Comment: Now i understand. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\left(54\right)\left(53\right)\left(52\right)\left(51\right)$
is actually a composite of permutations. Permution $\left(153\right)$ for instance sends $1$ to $5$, sends $5$ to $3$ and sends
$3$ to $1$. Here $2$ and $4$ (and eventually others) are untouched,
or equivalently are sent to themselves. Questioning where $1$ will
be sent to by $\left(54\right)\left(53\right)\left(52\right)\left(51\right)$ we find $\left(54\right)\left(53\right)\left(52\right)\left(51\right)\left(1\right)=\left(54\right)\left(53\right)\left(52\right)(5)=\left(54\right)\left(53\right)\left(2\right)=\left(54\right)\left(2\right)=2$.
Likewise we find that it sends $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $4$, $4$ to
$5$ and $5$ to $1$. So it can be recognized as permutation $\left(12345\right)$.
Composite $\left(54\right)\left(52\right)\left(21\right)\left(25\right)\left(23\right)\left(13\right)$
does exactly the same so can also be recognized as that permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually by a "cycle decomposition" one means writing a permutation as a product of *disjoint* cycles. So neither of your products of transpositions is a cycle decomposition.

More formally, a "product of disjoint cycles" is a product of the form $\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_n$ for $n\ge 0$, where every $\sigma_i$ is a cycle and $\sigma_i$ is disjoint from $\sigma_j$ unless $i=j$.

The case $n=0$ is the *empty product* which by definition is the identity element, so $e$.

In the case $n=1$ you have only one cycle, which is the product if itself and nothing else! This product automatically one of "disjoint cycles" in the vacuous sense that $i=j$ whenever $1\le i\le 1$ and $1\le j\le 1$.

You should have a theorem somewhere describing the uniqueness of cycle decomposition, so $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ is *itself* its own cycle decomposition, and is its *only* cycle decomposition, except for other ways to write down the *same* cycle, such as $(3\,4\,5\,1\,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$(13):(12345)->(32145)$

$(23)(13):(12345)->(23145)$

$(25)(23)(13):(12345)->(53142)$

$(21)(25)(23)(13):(12345)->(53241)$

$(52)(21)(25)(23)(13):(12345)->(23541)$

$(54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13):(12345)->(23451)$

Since $(12345)$ is identical with $(23451)$,

$(54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)=(23451)$